# Change url completely using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have url file which is `xxy.com/file1/file2/file3/file4/file5/something.pdf`.

This url is on `yyy.com`.

I don't want my users to know that pdf files are stored in different place.

So here what I want to do is:

Displaying `xxy.com` into `yyy.com`

Final output will look like:

`yyy.com/file1/file2/file3/file4/file5/something.pdf`.

Or if possible to `yyy.com/something.pdf`

And I don't need redirect. Once users click on the link they are supposed to see different url not the original url.

Comment: if you don't own the second domain (yyy.com) I don't think it's possible to fake that

Comment: i do own both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `mod_proxy` is enabled on `yyy.com` then put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file of `yyy.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?yyy\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?\.pdf)$ http://xxy.com/file1/file2/file3/file4/file5/$1 [L,NC,P]
```

Comment: Both of them are `wordPress` sites. I am not sure if I can add it to `wordpress` `.htaccess?` It does not seem to work. Then I created new `.htaccess` in `yyy.com/pathe1/path2` where my test.php have xxy.com URLs. It still does not work

Comment: As I suggested in me answer it needs to be placed in DOCUMENT_ROOT of `yyy.com` not in `yyy.com/path1/path2/`

Comment: Now I placed in DOCUMENT_ROOT of yyy.com, it still shows http://xxy.com/file1/file2/file3/file4/file5/something.pdf. Not yyy.com

Comment: That just means your `mod_proxy` isn't enabled.

Comment: How to check whether mod_proxy is enabled or not? Or how to enable it?

Comment: One such tutorial is this: http://abhirama.wordpress.com/2008/11/03/apache-mod_proxy-in-ubuntu/ if that doesn't work you need to contact server admin for your host.

Comment: I added your line to my wordpress .htaccess. It has already several other rewrite rules. I'm sure they are working, so it means mod_proxy is working right. Seems like i need root access to follow the tutorial. But I have my websites on shared server. Thus I cannot have root access.

Comment: Proxy can only be enabled from Apache config not from `.htaccess`. If you don' have server access then unfortunately you cannot get this working as they way you want.

Comment: Thank you! It worked finally once I gained root access to the server.

Comment: Just curious question, how do I do if I want it to display like, `yyy.com/path1/something.pdf` I did `RewriteRule ^path1/(.+?\.pdf)$ http://xxy.com/file1/file2/file3/file4/file5/$1 [L,NC,P]`. It didn't work. It would be nice if all my files are categorized into different paths.

Comment: Even for `/path1/something.pdf` my rule will work but not what you mean by `yyy.com/path1/something.pdf`

Comment: Yes...It does work. i forget escape\ in my rule. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need change HOST you can use mod_proxy module with ProxyPass directive

Put this lines in .htaccess on example.com

```
ProxyPass /something.pdf http://example.com/file1/file2/file3/file4/file5/something.pdf
```

*I use example.org because example.org are restricted here*

But you must check for mod_proxy enabled.

Or you can use php/other languages script to read remote file.

Comment: You can check it in php.ini and enable it if it is disabled.

Comment: You can't use `ProxyPass` or `ProxyPassMatch` in an htaccess file

Comment: Hi @Ster23, it's restricted to avoid accidentally linking to unrelated commercial websites. I made a small edit to use example.com instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `P` flag in mod_rewrite, which will internally pass the request to mod_proxy. That means you need to make sure both mod_rewrite and mod_proxy is loaded in your server config. Then you can use something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^something.pdf$ http://xxy.com/file1/file2/file3/file4/file5/something.pdf [L,P]
```

Comment: Can I store it in .htaccess in `http://xxy.com/file1/file2/file3/file4/file5/` folder? is it gonna work?

Comment: @user2090076 you need to store it in the document root of the site you want to access, not the xxy.com site. For example, if you want to access `http://yyyy.com/path1/path2/something.pdf`, then the rules need to go in the `/path1/path2/` folder on the yyyy.com server.

Comment: So this case I actually want to access pdf files on `xxy.com/file1/file2/file3/file4/file5/` from yyy.com. As you said I need to create .htaccess in .../file4/file5/ of xxy.com?

Comment: Then users click the URL, it will display yyy.com/file1/file2/file3/file4/file5/. I'm kind of confused. I created .htaccess both sites, none of them works

Comment: @user2090076 you create the htaccess file at the place that the URL in the browser says, you then want the URL of where the **file actually is** in the rewrite rule.